How to get Time-Course data for NOS2 & Arg1 Enzymes?
Background: I'm trying to model M1/M2 macrophage switch during a wound-healing process. For a switch from M1 cell population to M2 cell population, there is a reprogramming of the internal metabolic and signaling networks. Below is an example of the arginine metabolic switch. Arginine (i.e., the substrate) was initially getting converted to NO in M1-phages. In M2-phages, it starts getting converted into Urea.

NOS2 & Arg1 are the enzymes for the respective pathways. NOS2 stands for Nitric-Oxide Synthase (EC 1.14.13.39) and Arg1 stands for Arginase (EC 3.5.3.1).
Problem: I have 3 ODEs for the Metabolites (Arginine, NO, and Urea). I also have time-series data available (from literature) for each metabolite for parameter estimation. Furthermore, I have 2 ODEs for the enzyme concentration levels. But I cannot find time-course data for the enzymes. For parameter estimation, I need to minimize the ﬁt-error between the experimental and the predicted concentrations according to the formula:

But how can I do that without having experimental data points for enzyme levels?
I cannot find any data in the literature.
Is there any database that contains time-course data for enzyme levels?
